# Grok: how to match until first space (IIS Log)

Tags: regex, logstash-grok

I want to parse IIS logs.
one of the possible inputs is like the following

> 2017-10-01 00:00:01 W3SVC2 xx xx.xx.xx.xx GET
>   /CMSPages/PortalTemplate.aspx
>   **searchtext=excel-template-aa-xx-xx&xx=%2xx%2xx.com%yyyyy**
>   443 - yy.yy.yy.yy HTTP/1.1
>   Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+bingbot/2.0;++http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
>   - - www.yyyyy.com 410 0 64 0 335 32791

I can parse the above input until `searchtext` but I don't know how to get the search text?

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp}%{SPACE}%{WORD:machine}%{SPACE}%{WORD:ServerName}%{SPACE}%{IPV4:serverIP}%{SPACE}%{WORD:method}%{SPACE}%{URIPATH:uriStem}%{SPACE}%{WORD:searchTextWord}
```

is there any way to check if the `searchtext` exists then get the following text (until first space) as a search text.

Comment: @ctwheels yes, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/sPFsQE/1)

```
\bsearchtext=\S+
```

For Gork, make it optional:

```
(%{searchtext=\S+})?
```

Results in the following match:

> searchtext=excel-template-aa-xx-xx&xx=%2xx%2xx.com%yyyyy

---

### Explanation

- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `searchtext` Match this literally
- `\S+` Match any non-whitespace character one or more times